# How do I write a blocking synchronous method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, blocking, synchronous

I'm trying to mock out a method which takes a long time for testing purposes but can't find a good way to do this in Javascript. Any good approaches besides writing a very long for loop?

Comment: what wrong with a very long loop? or a loop that checks the time?

Comment: Nothing wrong, just wish I could do something like `sleep(milliseconds)`. It's harder to figure out how big the loop needs to be but nothing trial and error can't fix.

Comment: In Firefox you can use [trampolining](http://tobyho.com/2010/12/10/trampolines-in-javascript-and/ "Trampolines in Javascript and the Quest for Fewer Nested Callbacks") to make asynchronous JavaScript calls synchronous.

Comment: what about this: http://alexeypetrushin.github.io/synchronize/docs/index.html

Comment: I am looking for this so I can replace the alert( ) function without having to rewrite all of our alerts as asynchronous, so the sleep function definitely has a use case.  A 100% CPU core loop will not go over well. Async/Await might work with minimal code change, but not every browser supports the async pattern yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about [a loop that checks time](http://devcheater.com/)?

```
function sleep(milliSeconds){
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();                    // get the current time
    while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + milliSeconds); // hog cpu until time's up
}
```

Comment: Nice. Pretty obvious in hindsight.

Comment: This may cause the JavaScript engine to block other threads (browsers like Firefox < 4.0 will not allow the user to switch tabs or do anything else). Ultimately the browser will notice this and terminate your script. Not a good idea.

Comment: Works in Chrome, that's all I care about. This is obviously not going into any deployed code :)

Comment: @AaditMShah the OP just wanted something that acts like sleep. He didn't mention about what should happen while doing so.

Comment: this is not a good solution, at least not compared to Java's way of dealing with synchronizing code, but maybe it's a limitation of javascript

Comment: Why doesn't Javascript have this with 0% CPU usage?

Answer (score 4):

If you can use the newer await/await syntax:

```
function sleep (time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

async function example() {
    await sleep(4000);
    return 1;
}

console.log(await example());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a synchronous AJAX call to a server which defers the response by a certain amount of time as requested by your script. Note however that this method won't work in Firefox as it doesn't support synchronous AJAX calls.

Just use this simple function on the client side:

```
function sleep(microseconds) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.open("GET", "/sleep.php?time=" + milliseconds);
    request.send();
}
```

The code for `sleep.php` on the server side:

```
usleep(intval($_GET("sleep")));
```

Now you can create blocking synchronous functions in JavaScript (with the exception of Firefox) as follows:

```
alert("Hello");
sleep(1000000); // sleep for 1 second
alert("World");
```

Comment: This will burn up a socket connection for an extended period of time though.   These are limited.  Unless you are using node.js (or some asynchronous framework) it may have scaling issues.