# slow down webpage via javascript for a test

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, performance

To measure the impact of a slower webpage on the CTR of a button I'm trying to slow down the page in an optimizely test.

I can't find a proper way to do that with JavaScript, which would be needed for optimizely. To simulate a slower page (perceived performance) my first shot was hiding the page body `{ visibility: hidden }` for 1 second.

But, it resulted in a better CTR, since the browser kept loading the rest of the page and displayed the page with less flickering (all content was ready).

Then I tried the solution suggested here: [How do I write a blocking synchronous method in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527503/how-do-i-write-a-blocking-synchronous-method-in-javascript) 
with no satisfying result.

Any other ideas how I could set up the test (without using php `sleep()`)?

Comment: Have no idea whatsoever what `slow down page` means

Comment: Explain better what you are trying to achieve, I guess you are trying to simulate loading your webpage over slow connection.

Comment: current CTR = 8%, 1 sec delayed webpage CTR = 7%, 2 sec delayed  webpage CTR = 6%. with those numbers (in optimizely) it would be easy to convince my boss to improve performance.

Comment: Hide or mask `<body>` , set interval to show it using script